# Help in proving some Fourier transform property

Tags: fourier-transform, signal-processing

Knowing the integral property: $$\int_{-\infty}^tx(\tau)\,d\tau\,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\,\frac{X(\omega)}{j\omega}\,+\,\pi X(0)\delta(\omega)$$ and the inversion theorem: $$f(t)\,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\,g(\omega)\,\Rightarrow\,g(t)\,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\,2\pi f(-\omega)$$ 
 How can we prove that: $$\frac{-x(t)}{jt}\,+\,\pi x(0) \delta(t)\,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\,\int_{-\infty}^\omega X(\eta)\,d\eta$$

Here the $\,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\,$ denotes the Fourier transform defined as: $$X(\omega)\,=\,\int_{-\infty}^\infty\,x(t)\,e^{-j\omega t}\,dt$$So:$$\Rightarrow\,x(t)\,=\,\frac{1}{2\pi}\,\int_{-\infty}^\infty\,X(\omega)\,e^{j\omega t}\,d\omega$$ My question stems from the signals and systems course in the electrical engineering field, so here the Fourier transform should give us all of the available frequencies in the signal $x(t)$ ($x(t)$ models the signal's behavior in the time dimension): $$X(\omega)=2\pi.(\frac{available\,frequency}{d\omega})=2\pi.(frequency\,density)$$
Also the $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta function.
Here are two other properties that might be helpful in solving this question: $$x(-t)\,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\,X(-\omega)$$ $$x^*(t)\,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\,X^*(-\omega)$$ By $x^*(t)$ I mean the complex conjugate of $x(t)$.
 Let me know if anything needs further explanations.

Comment: I have no idea what any of this means. In particular, what does $\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow$ mean?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I apologize for the ambiguity. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that $f(t)\,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\,g(\omega)$ means that the Fourier transform of $f(t)$ is $g(\omega)$:
$$
g(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) e^{-i\omega t} dt
$$
By the Fourier inversion theorem one has
$$
f(t)\,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\,g(\omega)\,\Rightarrow\,g(t)\,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\,2\pi\,f(-\omega)
$$
so since
$$
\int_{-\infty}^tx(\tau)\,d\tau
\,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\,
\frac{X(\omega)}{j\omega}+\pi X(0)\delta(\omega)
$$
where $x(t)\,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\,X(\omega)$
you get
$$
\frac{X(t)}{jt}+\pi X(0)\delta(t)
\,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\,
2\pi\int_{-\infty}^{-\omega} x(\tau)\,d\tau
$$
Now we want to replace $X(t)$ with $x(t)$, but we need a Fourier transform in the left hand side. Luckily, since $x(t)\,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\,X(\omega)$, by the Fourier inversion theorem we have $X(t)\,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\,2\pi\,x(-\omega)$ so by replacing $X(t)$ with $2\pi\,x(-t)$ in the left hand side we can replace $x(\tau)$ with $X(\tau)$ in the right hand side:
$$
\frac{2\pi\,x(-t)}{jt}+\pi\,2\pi x(-0)\delta(t)
\,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\,
2\pi\int_{-\infty}^{-\omega} X(\tau)\,d\tau
$$
or after division with $2\pi$:
$$
\frac{x(-t)}{jt}+\pi\,x(-0)\delta(t)
\,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\,
\int_{-\infty}^{-\omega} X(\tau)\,d\tau
$$
Finally, changing $t$ to $-t$ in the left hand side is equivalent to changing $\omega$ to $-\omega$ in the right hand side, so we get
$$
\frac{x(t)}{j(-t)}+\pi\,x(0)\delta(-t)
\,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\,
\int_{-\infty}^{\omega} X(\tau)\,d\tau
$$
i.e.
$$
-\frac{x(t)}{jt}+\pi\,x(0)\delta(t)
\,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\,
\int_{-\infty}^{\omega} X(\tau)\,d\tau
$$

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be correct but shouldn't it be $x(-\tau)$ instead of $x(\tau)$ when you first apply the inversion theorem to the integral property? Maybe that's why you get $-\omega$ in the upper bound of the integral in the end instead of $\omega$.

Comment: Also when you apply the transform and replace $X(t)$ with $2\pi\,x(-t)$ shouldn't it be replaced with $2\pi\,x(-\omega)$ and shouldn't the integral bound in the right hand side change from $\omega$ to $t$? I mean shouldn't it go back to the time dimension? This was my problem.

Comment: You've found the place where I made an error. But it shouldn't be $x(-\tau)$. Instead it should be $-\omega$ as a limit of integration.

Comment: I have now fixed that sign error. Regarding your second question, I want $t$ on the left hand side and $\omega$ on the right hand side, so I don't think that you are correct there.

Comment: Excuse me sir, it still doesn't make sense. When you negate what's inside the definite integral and want it to instead affect the integral limits, then by what we know the bounds should be substituted so $\int_{b}^{a} (-x)\,dx$ becomes $\int_{a}^{b} x\,dx$ or $\int_{-b}^{-a} x\,dx$ instead of $\int_{b}^{-a} x\,dx$.

Comment: @FriendlyFella. Which step do you refer to in the first of your last two questions?

Comment: @FriendlyFella. Regarding your last question: Do you accept that $f(t)\,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\,g(\omega)$ implies $g(t)\,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\,2\pi\,f(-\omega)$? What do you think that it will give if you apply it on $\int_{-\infty}^tx(\tau)\,d\tau
\,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\,
\frac{X(\omega)}{j\omega}+\pi X(0)\delta(\omega)$?

Comment: Regarding my first question, I have made a mistake. Here is the part where I have my first question (also answering your second question): $\int_{-\infty}^tx(\tau)\,d\tau
\,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\,
\frac{X(\omega)}{j\omega}+\pi X(0)\delta(\omega)$ should give: $\frac{X(t)}{jt}+\pi X(0)\delta(t)
\,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\,
2\pi \int_{-\infty}^{\omega} x(-\tau)\,d\tau$. I just don't understand how $\int_{-\infty}^{\omega} x(-\tau)\,d\tau = \int_{-\infty}^{-\omega} X(\tau)\,d\tau$.

Comment: Here is the part where I have my second question: $\frac{X(t)}{jt}+\pi X(0)\delta(t)
\,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\,
2\pi\int_{-\infty}^{-\omega} x(\tau)\,d\tau$ can't be the same as $\frac{2\pi\,x(-t)}{jt}+\pi\,2\pi x(-0)\delta(t)
\,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\,
2\pi\int_{-\infty}^{-\omega} X(\tau)\,d\tau$. I think it should be $\frac{2\pi\,x(-\omega)}{j\omega}+\pi\,2\pi x(-0)\delta(\omega)
\,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\,
2\pi\int_{-\infty}^{-t} X(\tau)\,d\tau$.

Comment: @FriendlyFella. The first one uses $f(t)\,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\,g(\omega)\,\Rightarrow\,g(t)\,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\,2\pi\,f(-\omega)$ with $f(t)=\int_{-\infty}^tx(\tau)\,d\tau$ and $g(\omega)=
\frac{X(\omega)}{j\omega}+\pi X(0)\delta(\omega).$ So in the expression for $g(\omega)$ the variable $\omega$ should be replaced with $t$, and in the expression for $f(t)$ the variable $t$ should be replaced with $-\omega$ (and the expression should be multiplied with $2\pi$). Other variables should not be touched.

Comment: @FriendlyFella. $\frac{X(t)}{jt}+\pi X(0)\delta(t) \,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\, 2\pi\int_{-\infty}^{-\omega} x(\tau)\,d\tau$ is not the same as $\frac{2\pi\,x(-t)}{jt}+\pi\,2\pi x(-0)\delta(t) \,\overset{F}\longleftrightarrow\, 2\pi\int_{-\infty}^{-\omega} X(\tau)\,d\tau$. But if you accept that the first transform is valid for *any* function $x$ then it should also be valid if you replace $x$ with $X$ and $X$ with the Fourier transform of $X.$

Comment: Thank you very much. About the second one I thought the same as well, but it didn't make sense physically. It's all clearer now though. Thanks to your replies I can think better towards this subject.